# How to find multiple subsets of numbers that are approximately equal to a given value?

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, subset

I am using VBA that gets data from an Excel 2013 spreadsheet. I have a couple years experience in computer science from a while back using VBA and java, but I'm by no means an expert.

I have a column of numbers ranging from 20 to 60 total. Each of those numbers represents 'minutes' and can range from 3 to 500 (normally 60 to 300). Each number has an assigner called a 'load number' (such as N03, N22 and etc.) and a date/time. All of these values are attributed to a 'load' that needs to be picked. 'Pickers' are the ones that have the loads or minutes assigned to them. They can only pick so many minutes per given day which ranges from 400-600 (8 hour shift = 400 minutes).

What I need to do is assign sets of loads that are equal to an approximate amount of total minutes (set number w/ threshold) to two groups of pickers (The groups are AM and PM, each have 3-5 pickers). Once one load is assigned to a picker, it can't be assigned to another UNLESS the loads for a given day have too many minutes and all the pickers can't be assigned an approximate amount of minutes.

> *Example: Out of 8 pickers, 6 can be assigned loads totaling between 380-420 minutes, but 2 can't be assigned between 380-420 because of the remaining loads.*
>
> > In the case of the given example, for the remaining 2 pickers, a total of 760 - 840 minutes can be assigned to BOTH of them.

Loads also need to be assigned based on their date/time. If pickers are picking loads due on the same day, the earliest loads need to be assigned to the AM group of pickers and, accordingly, the latest to the PM group of pickers. If all loads to be assigned are for the next day, they can be assigned to anyone as long as the earliest loads are prioritized.

> *Example: AM shift starts at 5AM w/ 5 pickers. There is three loads that are 200 minutes (4 hours, actual) due at 9AM on the same day*
>
> > The three loads should be assigned to three different pickers, so the loads can be done on time. They would be marked as the #1 load, so each picker knows to do it first
>
> *Example: Another load is due at 9AM on the same day. It is 400 minutes though.*
>
> > 2 pickers can be assigned to this load as their #1 pick and 200 minutes would be assigned to both of them.

Once the loads are assigned to the pickers, the results will be displayed in a separate spreadsheet with each row having: AM/PM, Picker's name, Load number #'s 1-10 w/ load number and minutes to pick and the total minutes.

> *Example: PICKER | AM | Toby | 029-N10 (268), 030-N05 (93), 030-N04 (111) | 472 TOTAL*

Any help / pointers on this problem would be appreciated. I've looked at similar questions posted on here and abroad, but couldn't find any that would give me enough to go by to start working on a solution. It's not too bad assigning loads manually, but it gets complex one there's over 30 and 4,000 minutes total and especially when most of them are larger. It would just be much easier having a program assign everything and save 1-2 hours in the process everyday.

**Edit:**

The data, in Excel, is structured into 8 columns and up to 50 rows. Each row represents a 'load' and has only 3 useful cells. I got all the information into three arrays, which can be used to display the info for any load by using the same element (1-50) for each array.

> Dim **LoadNumbers**(1 To 50) As String
>
> Dim **LoadTime**(1 To 50) As Double
>
> Dim **LoadMinutes**(1 To 50) As Double
>
> Dim C As Integer
>
> C = 1
>
> Do While C < 50
>   
>   LoadNumbers(C) = Cells(C, 2)
>
> LoadTime(C) = Cells(C, 5) * 24
>
> LoadMinutes(C) = Cells(C, 7)
>
> C = C + 1
>   
>   Loop

For example:

> LoadNumbers(5) & " @ " & LoadTimes(5) & " Hours PST @ " & LoadMinutes(5) & " Minutes"

Will return:

> 039-N06  @ 9.5 Hours PST @ 67.4 Minutes (9.5 hours  = 9:30AM)

The **LoadTimes** and **LoadMinutes** arrays are the ones I need to assign loads. I will have another two cells that users will input the desired minutes (M) to be assigned and the threshold (T). I then need to VBA script to assign (M-T to M+T) minutes to each picker.

> Here's what the values in **LoadMinutes** look like:
>
> > 141.8
> >
> > 96
> >
> > 73.7
> >
> > 32.2
> >
> > 67.4
> >
> > 106.1
> >
> > 21.3
> >
> > 14.2
> >
> > 141.6
> >
> > 49.5
> >
> > 68.6
> >
> > 200.6
> >
> > 72
> >
> > 174.9
> >
> > 223.1
> >
> > 161.8
> >
> > 76.6
> >
> > 235.5
> >
> > 76.2
> >
> > 134.9
> >
> > 236.7
> >
> > 166.3
> >
> > 170.7
> >
> > 134.6
> >
> > 63.9
> >
> > 352.9
> >
> > 136.2
> >
> > 146.3
> >
> > 243.2
>
> There's 29 loads @ 3,818 minutes total

Lets say the minutes need to be between 430 to 470. Out of those 29 loads, I need to assign sets of different numbers adding up to 430 to 470 based on their time. The times in **LoadTimes** ranges from 7 to 20 (7AM to 8PM).

Comment: I think that the difficulty of this problem belongs to the *algorithmic* aspect more than the language and the tool. Your entry point should be [the subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). I't s known to be NP-Hard, but there are heuristics and for the case of a limited size, depending on this size you may even envisage a brute force method.

Comment: Hi @Jim , it is difficult to come up with a solution from scratch without knowing how the data is structured and clear understanding of what you are trying to do... This community works best when users attack a problem on their own and then come back with specific questions about specific lines or syntax they are not familiar with yet- so I suggest you write a macro that at least lands in the same state as what you are trying to do and then iterate from there.

Comment: I added more info to my question. I just need a general direction to go now. Such as pointing outing out any algorithms, like A.S.H. noted, that might apply. I looked up the 'subset sum problem' and haven't found anything specific to help me yet.